# Return from a Promise.all doesn't return from the wrapping function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to return from a function if some condition is met once `Promise.all` resolves. But the return statement doesn't seem to have an effect and the function execution continues.

Here's my code:

```
function somefunc() {

    Promise.all([match2, match3, match4, match5]).then(results => {
        console.log(results);
        if(results.indexOf(false) > -1) {
            return; // has no effect. somefunc() does NOT return. 
        }
        else {
            // ............
        };

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    // this continues to get executed even after the return staement
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return `Promise.all` if you want something in it's Promise chain to be returned:

```
function somefunc() {

    return Promise.all([match2, match3, match4, match5]).then(results => {
        console.log(results);
        if(results.indexOf(false) > -1) {
            return; // has an effect. somefunc() will return. 
        }
        else {
            // ............
        };

    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    // this will not get executed after the return staement
}
```

Comment: I added the `return` to the `Promise.all` but the code after the promise does continue to get executed.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.all([`  is resolve asynchronous, so `// this continues to get executed even after the return staement` will be always be executed before the code within the `then` runs.

You have to either use `await`/`async`:

```
async function somefunc() {
  try {
    var results = await Promise.all([match2, match3, match4, match5]);

    if (results.indexOf(false) > -1) {
      return;
    } else {
      // ............
    };
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  // code that is executed if return is not done
}
```

Or you need move the code of `// this continues to get executed even after the return staement` within the then, and you should `return` the Promise chain form your function, so that if someone calls `somefunc` is able to wait for the function to finish:

```
function somefunc() {

  return Promise.all([match2, match3, match4, match5]).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
    if (results.indexOf(false) > -1) {
      return; // has no effect. somefunc() does NOT return. 
    } else {
      // ............
    };

    // code that is executed if return is not done
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });
}
```